# uninitialized eq warning wwhen there is a regex match

Tags: regex, perl, mod-perl

I get a `uninitialized value in string eq at *** line xxx` warning in my code, which would be easy too fix if there actually was an`eq` at that line.

But there is a regular expression match on a value inside a hashref.

```
if ($hashref->{parameters}->{type} =~ m/:/) {
```

some lines before this I even have this:

```
$hashref->{parameters} = defined($hashref->{parameters}) ? $hashref->{parameters} : '';
$hashref->{parameters}->{type} = defined($hashref->{parameters}->{type}) ? $hashref->{parameters}->{type} : '';
```

so the value should be at least initialized.

I'm asking myself and you: why do I still get the warning that the value is uninitialized and moreover why does it say `eq` instead of `pattern match`

**Edit:**

The `parameters` subhash contains all variabels given via url input (post and/or get).
The `type` value is one of those variables which **could** be in the url.
It does not matter if or if not the `type` value is in the url, and if it contains a value, I always get an `uninitialized value in string eq` warning. Even if I control the value of type the line by warning it before the buggy line.

**2. edit:**
As @ikegami supposed there is indeed an `elsif` which caused the warning

The whole if - elsif statement looks somehow like:

```
if ($hashref->{parameters}->{type} =~ m/:/) {
    …
elsif ($hashref->{parameters}->{type} eq $somevalue) {
    …
}
```

and it was `$somevalue` that was uninitialized.

Comment: Can you show a broader context?

Comment: I believe $hashref->{parameters}->{type} is going to autovivify 
that key. That is, simply attempting to access it when it's not
there will end up creating it.

So, when you're checking the regex that key exists but is undefined.

Comment: @jmcneirney the possibility of autovivification should be intercepted be the two lines where I test if the values are defined?

Comment: +1 for broader context, if possible. Is there an 'eq' near this line? Sometimes, especially under an environment like mod_perl, the reported line number can be off due to peculiarities of the parser/optimizer.

Comment: There was an `eq` in the elsif, see the second edit/solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only showed half of the statement on that line. The full statement actually looks something like

```
456: if ($foo =~ /bar/) {
457:    ...
458: }
459: elsif ($baz eq 'qux') {
460:    ...
461: }
```

Run-time warnings for a statement normally use the line number at which the statement started, so if the regex doesn't match and `$baz` is undefined, you'll get a warning listing line 456 for the `eq` on line 459.

It's the same idea here:

```
$ perl -wE' my $x;  # 1
            say     # 2
            4       # 3
            +       # 4
            $x      # 5
            +       # 6
            5;      # 7 '
Use of uninitialized value $x in addition (+) at -e line 2.
9
```

Recently*, Perl was changed so that `elsif` conditions are considered a different statement to avoid this kind of problem. You must have an older version of Perl.

- — Actually, not so recently. Both 5.10 and 5.12 have been end-of-lifed, yet you appear to be using an even older version that that. If you're going to ask questions about a far-obsolete version of Perl, please mention it.

---

```
$ perlbrew use 5.10.1

$ perl -we'
my ($x,$y,$z);
if ($x) {
} elsif ($y eq $z) {
}'
Use of uninitialized value $y in string eq at -e line 4.
Use of uninitialized value $z in string eq at -e line 4.

$ perlbrew use 5.8.9

$ perl -we'
my ($x,$y,$z);
if ($x) {
} elsif ($y eq $z) {
}'
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at -e line 3.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at -e line 3.
```

Comment: False. You'll get the warning on line 459, as in: 'Use of uninitialized value $baz in string eq at try.pl line 459.'

Comment: @zostay, False. You'll get a warning on line 456 or 459 depending on your version of Perl. He's probably using pre-5.10 since there's no variable named in error message.

Comment: That's possible. The oldest Perl I have installed on this machine is Perl 5.10. If using Perl 5.8, I'd recommend upgrading your Perl.

Comment: @zostay, See addition at the bottom of my post.

Comment: I'm actually running Perl 5.10.1 therefore I'm wondering why I don't get the warning with the variable name. But you pointed me into the right direction nevertheless. Thanks